# How to setting RabbitMQ?

Tags: rabbitmq

I just install RabbitMQ in my computer and want to run demo for sending message but it doesn't work. According to [documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-php.html) the reason may because the broker was started without enough free disk space. And when I check RabbitMQ Management Dashboard, it show my free disk space only 46kb (by default it needs at least 200 MB free). According to documentation I need to change `disk_free_limit`.

From [this](https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html#config-items) documentation I have to create configuration file by myself and put it in `C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\RabbitMQ`. The documentation give an [example](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/blob/master/deps/rabbit/docs/rabbitmq.conf.example) script for configuration. I change the setting for `disk_free_limit.absolute`, restart computer (I don't know how to restart RabbitMQ service in windows). But when I check the RabbitMQ Management Dashboard the disk space still 46kb.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend the usage of containers for running services like RabbitMQ to avoid problems like the ones you are having at the moment.

- I usually use this dockerfile

```
FROM rabbitmq:3-management
RUN echo '[rabbitmq_management,rabbitmq_management_visualiser,rabbitmq_amqp1_0].' > enabled_plugins
RUN rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_amqp1_0
```

- For running it

```sh
docker build -t my-rabbit .
docker run -it --rm --name rabbitmq -p 5672:5672 -p 15672:15672 my-rabbit:latest
```

If you never played with docker before, please read [this](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/overview/).

Comment: I'll try install in Ubuntu first. If it still not working i'll use docker

Comment: Ubuntu? Well, if you are running Windows you can use docker. https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/install/

Comment: I mean install rabbitmq in my ubuntu desktop. BTW, I saw in youtube they can install rabbitmq in windows without docker. So I think it can run well without docker.

Comment: Yes, it should work well without docker. But if you use it, you shouldn't have any configuration problem as it runs in a very strict context / sandbox. That's why I am suggesting it, when you need to run services like this locally, you should spin up a docker instead of configuring it by yourself (apart from, it might be out-of-the-box installation the rabbitmq for windows, give it a try)